# SVN ignore not working

Tags: svn

I'm trying to make subversion ignore a folder, so I did from the parent folder:

```
svn propset svn:ignore folder-to-ignore .
```

but the `svn st` is still listing the files within that folder with a "?" (not on version control).

I want to ignore the folder itself (which is on version control), as there are always new files inside it.

Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: I've found that it doens't like the preceding "./" on the dir name or a trailing slash. (svn, version 1.6.18).  Use 'svn propedit svn:ignore .' to see if you have that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the folder (or a file) is already in version control, it cannot be ignored. But you can ignore all files inside that folder — just set the `svn:ignore` property on that folder instead:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "*" folder-to-ignore
```

The folder itself will still be tracked (and created on a new checkout).

Comment: I did a little more deleting and updating and checking out, I don't know exactly what I did, but it was successful ignored now..

Comment: to set svn:ignore on all files and folder, using DOS:  svn propset svn:ignore \"*\" *

Answer (score 19):

I have struggled with the same problem and learned that the the command must be run in the parent folder and that the ignored directory can not be a sub directory. Assume I have the following structure and wish to ignore *virtualenv*:

```
project/
project/.svn/
project/trunk/
project/trunk/virtualenv/
```

When in the `project` folder the following will **not** work as expected:

```
svn propset svn:ignore trunk/virtualenv .
```

However the following will work:

```
cd trunk
svn propset svn:ignore virtualenv .
```

OR

```
svn propset svn:ignore virtualenv trunk/
```

This is actually the expected behaviour, see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html and search for ignore information.

**Note**: If the folder was already tracked you can untrack it with `svn remove <FOLDER> --keep-local`